# How many calls of the form $\det(B)$ does the algorithm create?

Tags: matrices, recursive-algorithms, discrete-optimization

Let's say $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and the $n^2$ components of $A$ are pairwise different. In order to calculate $\det(A)$ we can use the recursive algorithm that computes $\det(A) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} (−1)^{1+j}a_{1j} \det(A_{1j})$ where $A_{1j}$ is the matrix obtained by deleting its first row and j-th column.

```
Input: A ∈ Rn×n 
Output: det(A) 
if (n = 1)
    return a11 
else
    d := 0
    for j = 1,...,n
        d := (−1)^{1+j}det(A_{1j}) + d
    return d
```

Suppose that B is a matrix that can be obtained from A by deleting the first k rows and k of
the columns of A. How many (recursive) calls of the form det(B) does the algorithm create?

My first idea was that it creates $k!$ calls(**1st question: can you confirm that and is my explenation sufficient?**). Basically "every permutation of the k columns" if it makes sense. A certain call leads to different ones and the only way to get $\det(B)$ call is to choose the columns that are deleted every time. Here is a drawing for $n=5$ and $k=3$:

[image: n=5, k=3 example]

I don't get why we need to suppose that all the coefficients of $A$ are pairwise different. Is it to insure that every sub-matrix is unique so #{calls of the form det(B)} means the calls for a specific $B$ can only be obtained by specific deleted rows and columns? (deleting two different sets of columns can't give the same sub-matrix, so it's kind of the well definition of $\{(i_l,j_l)\ l=1,...,k\}\rightarrow $ "matrix obtained by deleting rows and columns associated to the $(i_l,j_l)$'s"). **2nd question: can you confirm that the pairwise different coefficient condition is indeed to make every sub-matrix unique?**

The second question is: How many different submatrices can be obtained from $A$ by deleting the first $k$ rows and some set of $k$ columns?

So I found $\binom{n}{k}$. **3rd question: I guess just confirm that number please.**

Conclude that the algorithm remains exponential, even if it does not expand repeated subcalls.

So here we assume that for any sub-matrix, its determinant will only be calculated once. But because every sub-matrix is unique, we're still going to have to expand the call once. The algorithm calls it self more than once so it is exponential but I feel like I'm not giving enough explenation, plus I'm not really using the "even if it does not expand repeated subcalls" information...
**4th question: can you comment on the complexity of the algorithm given the above information please?**

Thank you

Comment: $k!$ for $det(B)$ part seems correct. That means you compute the same determinant $k!$ many times. Do you ask the complexity for this algorithm or for the dynamic version? And your second question has positive answer. If two sub matrices are the same then all their entries are the same which forces them to be the same sub matrix. 3rd question also has positive answer.

Comment: @Levent the algorithm given that it does not expand repeated sub calls. What is a dynamic version?

Comment: I mean calculating the same determinant $k!$ times does not really make sense right? You can start by computing $2\times 2$ determinants, and then $3\times 3$ determinants using $2\times 2$ determinants and go up inductively (note that computing the determinant is a heavily researched subject and there are much more better algorithms).